# Hooking up an event with custom args to a reactive-ui command in a PCL

Tags: windows-store-apps, caliburn.micro, reactiveui

I have a GridView and the IsItemClickEnabled is set to true. In this case, the ItemClick event is fired, and it calls a delegate with a sender and an ItemClickEventArgs. I'm using MVVM (Caliburn.Micro), and my view models are all sitting in a portable class library (PCL). All command routing, etc., is done by Reactive-UI. The View's data context is set to the view model, as you might expect.

The problem is ItemClickEventArgs is not available in a PCL configuration as far as I can tell. So I am currently at a loss as how to sink that event in my view model. Heck - even without using a reactive ui command.

Here is my grid view defined:

```
        <GridView x:Name="PaperList" Margin="0" Grid.Column="1" IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemClick="whatgoeshere?"/>
```

My simplest idea is to replace "whatgoeshere?" with a method in the view's code-behind, for example:

```
    public void ForkItUp(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs args)
    {
        // How do I get this information back to the view model?
    }
```

And of course, that works, that method gets called. But once I'm there, how the heck do I get the information back into my View Model? As far as I know the view knows nothing about the view model.

The only thing I can think of is I need to create some property that contains the PCL object that was clicked on. This method would stuff the item into that property, and through some magic of data-binding that would be sent back to the view model. If so, I have no idea how to participate in the data-binding process to get that right! Ack! :-)

I don't know if this makes a difference yet, but I'm not using universal apps! And I'm using a nasty hybrid of Caliburn.Micro to hook up my views, and Reactive-ui and rx to run all my commands. I don't like making anything easy!

Comment: One way to do it is to take the DataContext, cast it to the proper type, and then call directly with the selected item as an argument. This works... Is this the best way to do it, however?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I would do it

```
ReactiveCommand ItemClicked { get; protected set; }

public MyCoolViewModel()
{
    ItemClicked = new ReactiveCommand();
}

// In My View
gridView.ItemClicked += (o,e) => ViewModel.ItemClicked.Execute(e.Item);
```

> As far as I know the view knows nothing about the view model.

This isn't how MVVM works - the View can know all *kinds* of stuff about the ViewModel, that's the whole idea! However, the ViewModel can know **nothing** about any Views.

Comment: Ah, good point. I think of neither really knowing much about each other - that is what the framework does.

Answer (score 0):

I found two different approaches worked, based on the answer that Paul gave. I ended up using the second. In the first approach I added a public method to my MyViewModel:

```
public void ClickOnTile(PaperTileViewModel pt)
{
    code to run;
}
```

Then, in my View I added the following:

```
public void ForkItUp(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs args)
{
    var obj = DataContext as MyViewModel;
    obj.ClickOnTile(args.ClickedItem as PaperTileViewModel);
}
```

And the XAML for my view for the grid view:

```
<GridView x:Name="PaperList" Margin="0" Grid.Column="1" IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemClick="ForkItUp"/>
```

I'm a C++ guy by training, so the lack of type safety got to me a bit and lead to this second solution (which is the one that I ended up committing). So I ended up doing the following in the end. I first created an interface in my ViewModel's PCL:

```
public interface IHomePageViewCallback
{
    void FinalizeVMWiring(HomePageViewModel homePageViewModel);
}
```

Then, in the View I implemented the interface:

```
public sealed partial class MyPageView : Page, IHomePageViewCallback
{
    public MyPageView()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void FinalizeVMWiring(MyViewModel myVM)
    {
        PaperList.ItemClick += (s, args) => myVM.NavigateToPaperTile.Execute((args.ClickedItem) as PaperTileViewModel);
    }
}
```

where NavigateToPaperTile is a ReactiveCommand similar to what Paul has in his answer. This funny call back is needed because as far as I can tell there is no easy way to get a typed version of the ViewModel in Caliburn.Micro.

For completeness here is the XAML:

```
        <GridView x:Name="PaperList" Margin="0" Grid.Column="1" IsItemClickEnabled="True"/>
```